# Can I sand/ paint these cabinets

Tags: painting

Is it possible to sand these cabinets, and paint them? Any suggestions?

Can’t afford to replace all of the cabinets, so we wanted to try painting them instead. After that we’d also be adding new hinges and knobs to them.[image]

Comment: Are they Formica or real wood?

Comment: Pretty sure they’re Formica

Comment: You can't afford to replace the cabinets, but could you afford to replace the doors?  I think replacing the doors and painting the face frames to match would be a lot easier than sanding and painting the existing doors.  Just painting the frames would be less area to F up.  YMMV depending on budget, skill, and tolerance for flaws (i.e. DGAF factor).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like veneer, which is pretty thin layer of nice-looking wood on top of cheaper plywood. As such, the sanding need to be either avoided or done very carefully. In any case, the advice is to find "inconspicuous area" to try our your method. In your case, I would take one of the doors off and use inside surface as a playground.

if you want to [paint it with solid color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-eDlk2rlN4), then sanding + priming is a requirement.

Comment: Okay. Yeah, they’re veneer. Pretty sure these are the original cabinets, so they’re from 1980. 

Would refacing them be the better option then? They’re in fairly good condition. Just never done something like that before, but it seems doable.

Comment: Thanks for including that video by the way! It looked like they didn’t have to sand it down as much as I thought. Just enough for the primer to stick, is that correct?

Comment: @aaronh i think the general recommendation is to do light 180 grit sanding